# IOS Background task with specific time interval

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cllocationmanager

I wanted to call a service with some interval like 24 hour. So if my app is in background also at that time also it should call for that service. I am supporting location updates, so my app will run in background. But i want to know how can i execute some task with time interval without informing user.
Thanks

Comment: If you are not a navigation app but you are requesting constant location updates I think your app my be rejected. As well you will really hurt battery life.

Comment: What type of location update you are doing. Continuous or significant location changes?

Comment: No Only region monitor

Comment: With region monitoring, you won't receive any kind of update if you don't travel as far as many blocks away. And it is true, if you're registering for background location services just for the sake of keeping your app running in background, Apple will reject.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can think of would be to integrate with [Parse](http://parse.com).  There you can set up cloud code that runs in the background at a specific time.  You can also schedule push notifications as needed.  Otherwise, this is a fairly difficult situation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `NSThread` methods to call your service in background after some time interval.

You can follow this [link1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [link2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) for understanding of thread management.

Hope this will help..

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use this code in your app delegate  didfinishlaunching method
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidTimeout:) name:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];

and set timer according to that to perform your task at a particular time
```

Comment: NSTimer will not fire while the app is suspended. It will fire instead when the app is next foregrounded.